# Python Tkinter - Using the command feature

Tags: python, tkinter

I am playing around with tkinter, and I wanted to apply it to a problem i'm trying to work through.  the base code is based on the tutorial found under the "A Simple Hello World Program" found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html.
I am changing into a directory, creating a list of that directory and creating checkbuttons based on the files found there.  When i check or un-check one of the checkbuttons currently, it prints "hi there, everyone!" to the console.

Assume os.listdir() returns:
my_list = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5]

ultimately i want to get a dictionary with the filename and the state of the checkbutton like this:

my_dict{file1:1, file2:0, file3:0, file4:1, file5:1}.

I also need this to be updated in real-time until the program ends.

I could do this if I manually created each checkbutton individually, but the number of files will change from time to time and I would rather not have to come back and change my script every time a file is added or removed.

How can I get the variable of each generated checkbutton and update that value in the dictionary anytime it is checked/unchecked?

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

os.chdir('c:\\some\\path\\here')
my_list = os.listdir()
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
    for filename in my_list:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        self.filename = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=filename, variable=var, command=self.check_state)
        self.items[filename] = var #this is where i'm getting the 'application has no member' error
        self.filename.pack(side="top")

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

def check_state(self):
    my_dict = {filename:self.items[filename].get() for filename in self.items} #getting the same 'application has no member' error here as well
    print(my_dict)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"every time a file is added or removed."***: You didn't show how you do this, you create the `Button`'s **once** from `my_list`. To *remove* a `Button` you need a reference or make it `self.destroy()`

Comment: the buttons are generated by the create_widgets function.  the files are not going to be added or deleted automatically.  for the most part, the files will remain untouched.  however, they will be added periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` with filename as the key and `IntVar` as the value, and then generate the required `dict` in `check_state()`:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.items = {}   # holds filename:IntVar
    for filename in my_list:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=filename, variable=var, command=self.check_state)
        cb.pack(side="top")
        self.items[filename] = var

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

def check_state(self):
    print("hi there, everyone!")
    my_dict = {filename:self.items[filename].get() for filename in self.items}
    print(my_dict)
    # or use self.my_dict if it is used by other instance functions
```

Comment: This appears to be going in the direction i am needing.  i modified my code to reflect these changes, but I get the error "Instance of 'Application' has no 'items' member".  I have never encountered this error before.  could you elaborate as to why I might be receiving this please?

Comment: It is difficult to help without your modified code.

Comment: i updated the code above and added comments next to the lines in questions.  the portion specifically that's causing the problem is the "self.items" in each line.

Comment: You did not include the change `self.items = {}` in `create_widgets()`.

Comment: you are correct.  I completely overlooked that line.  I appreciate the help.  I have marked this as the answer.  I can do the rest of what i need from here.